# Thinking Sphinx: "sort-by attribute `published_at` not found` in test environment

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I'm getting the error `sort-by attribute 'published_at' not found`, but only in test environment, even after rebuilding.

In the model:

```
belongs_to :content, polymorphic: true
belongs_to :user

define_index do
  indexes user.name, as: :name
  has role
  has user_id
  has content_id
  has content.published_at, as: :published_at, type: :datetime
  has content.status, as: :status, type: :integer
end
```

Running `rake ts:rebuild` in **development** properly builds the index:

```
# development.sphinx.conf
{
  [...]
  sql_attr_uint = sphinx_internal_id
  sql_attr_uint = sphinx_deleted
  sql_attr_uint = class_crc
  sql_attr_uint = role
  sql_attr_uint = user_id
  sql_attr_uint = content_id
  sql_attr_uint = status
  sql_attr_timestamp = published_at
  sql_attr_string = sphinx_internal_class
  [...]
}
```

However, running `RAILS_ENV=test rake ts:config` or `ts:rebuild` for the **test** environment generates this:

```
# test.sphinx.conf
{
  [...]
  sql_attr_uint = sphinx_internal_id
  sql_attr_uint = sphinx_deleted
  sql_attr_uint = class_crc
  sql_attr_uint = role
  sql_attr_uint = user_id
  sql_attr_uint = content_id
  sql_attr_string = sphinx_internal_class
  [...]
}
```

This, of course, leads to an error in the **test** environment:

```
ThinkingSphinx::SphinxError:
  index content_byline_core: sort-by attribute 'published_at' not found
```

Notice the missing `status` and `published_at` attributes. This has been working for the past few months, but I don't know what could have caused it to break.

- Sphinx 2.0.2-beta
- Thinking Sphinx 2.0.12
- Rails 3.2.6
- Ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem while using Zeus. rake spec works but when i use zeus i got similar messages did you figure that out ? For me removing zeus helps but it is only a partial solution ...